# android : External jar files adding?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add some external jar files in my project. 
Anyone tell me how to add external jar files to current project? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Apparently all the answers make reference to eclipse.  How is this done from ant build.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, check the manual: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm :

> [..] the project properties (Project > Properties > Java Build Path)

And then click '*Add external JAR*'.

If you're using IntelliJ, check out these StackOverflow questions: [how to add directory to classpath in an application run profile in intellij idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854264/how-to-add-directory-to-classpath-in-an-application-run-profile-in-intellij-idea) and [how to add a jar to my lib/ directory in intelliJ and have the classes available for my web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533428/how-to-add-a-jar-to-my-lib-directory-in-intellij-and-have-the-classes-available).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do that,

1.)    `Right click on your Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External JARS...`

2.) You can create a `lib` folder in your Project folder and copy the JAR file in that folder, then

```
right click the JAR file from the eclipse Package explorer -> Build Path-> Add to Build Path
```

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse right click on your project -> properties->java build path ->Libraries tab

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps :
right click project

open properties of project ->java build path -> libraries -> add external jar

path of ur jar file

hope this will help u....