# How to integrate external librarys (libs) into a grails project?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, intellij-idea, htmlunit

I've a new grails 2.0 project and i want to integrate HtmlUnit-Libraries into it.
I just moved the HtmlUnit 2.9 libs into the "lib"-Folder of my grails project and used them in my grails-service. When i start my application, using intelliJ 11 IDE, it doesn't start because grails can't find the imports.

In my Service class i did:

```
 import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient
 import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion
```

After starting the grails run-app script, i get the following exception:

```
/Users/whitenexx/Workspaces/sts-workspace/OMTool/grails-app/services/omtool/TestService.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion
@ line 4, column 1.
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion^
```

How do I integrate java-libraries into an grails project?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of copying the jar into the `/lib` directory, try specifying it in `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        compile 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.9'
    }
}
```

Comment: Dependency to htmlunit must have 'compile' scope, because it's used in non-test code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the jars to your buildpath?

Comment: That's the problem. In eclipse/sts is an contextoption called "buildpath". I can't find a similar option in intelliJ. Or do i have to edit the buildpath elsewhere?

Comment: This isn't the same thing you are looking at but they explain how to do that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533428/how-to-add-a-jar-to-my-lib-directory-in-intellij-and-have-the-classes-available

Comment: Hmmm..I'm not an idea user so I can't play around with it. Are any other classes being used from those packages giving you trouble? Maybe it is just that .jar...

Comment: When i use plain grails without IDE, it should work? I would like to use sts/eclipse but the newest grails 2.0 isn't supported yet.

Comment: Should work. I use netbeans for my grails development and it's pretty nice. I only use plugins to use functionality though..not sure if this will help your issue but but it looks like you aren't suppose to include the xml-apis-*.jar in your classpath when you use HtmlUnit with grails.

Comment: You don't have to care about "buildpath", all jars in '/lib' folder will automatically  added to "buildpath".

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem，solved already. specifying it in BuildConfig.groovy.

```
dependencies {

    compile('net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.9') {
        excludes 'xml-apis' 
    }
}
```

if not take effect，you can clean your grails ivy-cache first and  try it again.