# Install Selenium webdriver with intellij on mac os x

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

I am a newbie in selenium, trying to learn step by step. I have a system - Mac os x 10.6.8 with current jdk 1.6. Please help me with the instructions on how to install Selenium webdriver  set up with Intellij 12 on this mac. I found various articles on windows but I have a hard time to find one for mac.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to manage your dependencies, but if it is too complicated for your project - just add the Java? [webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) to your path in intellij

See example: [how to add a jar to my lib/ directory in intelliJ and have the classes available for my web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533428/how-to-add-a-jar-to-my-lib-directory-in-intellij-and-have-the-classes-available)