# Using ispeech.org TTS in Android app

Tags: android, intellij-idea, text-to-speech, ispeech

I am having trouble using ispeech.org TTS engine with my Android app.

The app crashes on:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ispeech.iSpeechFramework
        at            org.ispeech.SpeechSynthesis.showProcessingDialog(SpeechSynthesis.java:276)
        at org.ispeech.SpeechSynthesis.speak(SpeechSynthesis.java:352)
```

I have added this line to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="org.ispeech.iSpeechFramework" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

However IntelliJ complains that

"'org.ispeech.iSpeechFrameworkd' is not assignable to 'app.android.Activity'"

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: iSpeechFramework isn't an android activity, so it does not go in your manifest like that.

Answer (score 0):

org.ispeech.iSpeechFramework is not an activity, so you don't need to add it to your manifest. NoClassDefFoundError is usually a linker/build path error. Try removing the jar and adding it with the instructions in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320035/1991067).

If it helps at all, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16610247/1991067) is how you would fix it in Eclipse.